# Binary Coded Decimal Counter in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, counter, bcd

I have written this BCD-Counter in VHDL but the 10th place counter counts up every clock cylce instead of once, so instead of going from 09 to 10, the output is 09,19,29,39,... until bcd1_overflow is '0' again as you can see in the screenshot.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Counter7Segments is
  port(
    clk : in std_logic;
    reset : in std_logic;
    segments_1 : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    segments_10 : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)
  );
end Counter7Segments;

architecture rtl of Counter7Segments is

component ClockEnableGenerator is
  generic(
    DIVIDE_BY : integer
  );

  port(
    clk_in : in std_logic;
    clk_en_out : out std_logic;
    reset : in std_logic
  );
end component;

component GenericBCDCounter is
  generic(
    COUNT_MAX : integer
  );

  port(
    clk : in std_logic;
    enable : in std_logic;
    reset : in std_logic;
    count : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    overflow : out std_logic
  );
end component;

component BCDDecoder is
  port(
    digit : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    segments : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)
  );
end component;

signal clock_seconds : std_logic;
signal count_1 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal count_10 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal bcd1_overflow : std_logic;

begin

Clock : ClockEnableGenerator
  generic map(
    DIVIDE_BY => 13
  )

  port map(
    clk_in => clk,
    clk_en_out => clock_seconds,
    reset => reset
  );

Counter_1 : GenericBCDCounter
  generic map(
    COUNT_MAX => 9
  )

  port map(
    clk => clk,
    enable => clock_seconds,
    reset => reset,
    count => count_1,
    overflow => bcd1_overflow
  );

Counter_10 : GenericBCDCounter
  generic map(
    COUNT_MAX => 5
  )

  port map( 
    clk => clk,
    enable => bcd1_overflow,
    reset => reset,
    count => count_10,
    overflow => open
  );

Decoder_1 : BCDDecoder
  port map(
    digit => count_1,
    segments => segments_1
  );

Decoder_10 : BCDDecoder
  port map(
    digit => count_10,
    segments => segments_10
  );

end architecture rtl;
```

[image: The simulation output]

I tried having a synchronous bcd1_overflow_pulse, but it was off by some clock cyles, also I tried making the condition for Counter_10 to count up "bcd1_overflow and clock_seconds" but that didn't work either.

If you want to try something out with my code, here is the code for the components I used:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity BCDDecoder is

port(
  digit : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  segments : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)
);

end BCDDecoder;

architecture rtl of BCDDecoder is

begin

process(digit)
begin
  if(digit = "0000") then
    segments <= "1111110";
  elsif(digit = "0001") then
    segments <= "0110000";
  elsif(digit = "0010") then
    segments <= "1101101";
  elsif(digit = "0011") then
    segments <= "1111001";
  elsif(digit = "0100") then
    segments <= "0110011";
  elsif(digit = "0101") then
    segments <= "1011011";
  elsif(digit = "0110") then
    segments <= "1011111";
  elsif(digit = "0111") then
    segments <= "1110000";
  elsif(digit = "1000") then
    segments <= "1111111";
  elsif(digit = "1001") then
    segments <= "1111011";
  end if;
end process;

end architecture rtl;
```

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity ClockEnableGenerator is

generic(
  DIVIDE_BY : integer
);

port(
  clk_in : in std_logic;
  reset : in std_logic;
  clk_en_out : out std_logic
);

end ClockEnableGenerator;

architecture rtl of ClockEnableGenerator is

signal counter : unsigned(3 downto 0) := "0000";

begin

process(clk_in, reset)
begin
  if(reset = '1') then
    clk_en_out <= '0';
    counter <= "0001";
  elsif(rising_edge(clk_in)) then
    if(counter = DIVIDE_BY - 1) then
      counter <= (others => '0');
      clk_en_out <= '1';
    else
      clk_en_out <= '0';
      counter <= counter + 1;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;

end architecture rtl;
```

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity GenericBCDCounter is

generic(
  COUNT_MAX : integer
);

port(
  clk : in std_logic;
  reset : in std_logic;
  enable : in std_logic;
  count : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  overflow : out std_logic
);

end GenericBCDCounter;

architecture rtl of GenericBCDCounter is

signal value : unsigned(3 downto 0);

begin

process(clk)
begin
  if(reset = '1') then
    value <= (others => '0');
    overflow <= '0';
  elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then
    if(enable = '1') then
      if(value = COUNT_MAX) then
        value <= (others => '0');
      else
        value <= value + 1;
      end if;

      if(value + 1 = COUNT_MAX) then
        overflow <= '1';
      else
        overflow <= '0';
      end if;
    else
      if(value = COUNT_MAX) then
        overflow <= '1';
      else
        overflow <= '0';
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;

count <= std_logic_vector(value);

end architecture rtl;
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with emphasis on "complete."

Comment: count_10 is counting multiple times. It's enabled when BCD Count_1 rolls is "1001" (9). An enable for count_10 can be the AND of Count_1's enable (valid for 1 clock) and the output indicating "count_1 = 1001" to  provide a single count_10 increment. A [mcve] would provide a testbench allowing the problem to be reproduced and a solution demonstrated. Minimal imples BCDDecoder need not be included (nor in a waveform image which could be supplanted by a specific problem describing successive clocks when count_10's enable is '1'). You can answer yourself.

Comment: While excepting an answer for a problem that can't be reproduced nor the solution verified without a testbench gets you an answer you can use what about future readers who can't see the see the problem or solution hands on, lacking the ability? Note that the busybee didn't tell you the GenericBCDCounter process sensitivity list is missing reset, part of the if statement isn't needed (nor why) and overflow doesn't need to be a flip flop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you clock the tens' counter `Counter_10` with `clk` and enable it with `bcd1_overflow`, which is `1` during multiple clock cycles. With each clock it advances, as you observed.

One possible solution is to AND `clock_seconds` and `bcd1_overflow` before using it to enable `Counter_10`.